# $G$ is finite, $A \leq G$ and all double cosets $AxA$ have the same cardinality, show that $A \triangleleft G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a finite group and $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that all double cosets $AxA$ have the same number of elements, show that $gAg^{-1}=A$ for all $g \in G$.

Here is my attempt, I guess it's correct but please verify it. I looked for this problem on the internet but I found it nowhere, so I thought it might be a good idea to have an answer for it on MSE:

We know that for $x,y \in G$ we have $|AxA|=|AyA|$ by hypothesis of the problem.

In particular for any $g \in G$ we have $|AgA|=|AeA|=|AA|=|A|$. In other words, all double cosets $AgA$ have the same number of elements as $A$ for any $g \in G$.

Now, we use the following counting formula:

$$|AxB|=\frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap xBx^{-1}|}$$

with $A=B$ and $ \forall g \in G:|AgA|=|A|$  we obtain:

$$ |A| = \frac{|A||A|}{|A \cap gAg^{-1}|} \implies |A \cap gAg^{-1}|=|A| $$

But $A \cap gAg^{-1} \subseteq A$ and since $G$ is finite and $|A \cap gAg^{-1}|=|A|$ it forces $A \cap gAg^{-1} = A$.

That implies $A \subseteq gAg^{-1}$ for any $g \in G$, which is the same as $g^{-1}Ag \subseteq A$ for any $g \in G$ and this proves the normality of $A$ in $G$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Perfectly correct proof.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Thanks.

Comment: @some1.new4u I will split this and put your solution in the question as answer. I.e., I would give this an answered question format.

Comment: @amWhy: I actually think the other question is a duplicate of this one. Just saying. :) This one has been asked 3 years before that one.

Answer (score 1):

The proof mentioned in the question is perfectly correct.